# Embed generic new() constraint into interface/class?

Tags: c#, generics

So far I've been adding `new()` constraint like this.

```
public T Request<T>(BaseRequest request)
        where T : BaseResponse, new()
```

Is there a way to bake the `new()` into `BaseResponse` so that I only need to specify

```
        where T : BaseResponse
```

Comment: If you have these checks over several methods in your class, consider making the class itself generic, so that you only have one constraint at the class level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. A derived class can always have a private/protected constructor, and there's no way to prevent that. It might even be an abstract class.

The only exception are `struct`s, which always have a default constructor - the one you get with `default(SomeStruct)`. Needless to say, this simply means the struct is initialized with zeroes (though C# 6 made this a bit more complicated).

Answer (score 1):

The only way you could spare some typing, provided you have several generic methods in your class, is to make the *class* generic instead, i.e. go from this:

```
class YourClass
{
    public static T Request<T>(BaseRequest request)
       where T : BaseResponse, new()
    { }

    public static T SomethingElse<T>(BaseRequest request)
       where T : BaseResponse, new()
    { }
}
```

to this:

```
class YourClass<T> where T : BaseResponse, new()
{
    public static T Request(BaseRequest request)
    { }

    public static T SomethingElse(BaseRequest request)
    { }
}
```